# Python: uninstall a ghost package

Tags: python, import, pip

I've got a project `damastes`, which introduced two packages, `damastes` and `procrustes`:

```
>>> import damastes
>>> import procrustes
```

I removed the `procrustes` package from the project, without changing the `damastes` project version, rebuilt and reinstalled the project:

```
$ poetry build
$ pip install dist/damastes... --user -I
```

but

```
>>> import procrustes
```

is still very much alive. It won't show on `$ pip list`, and why should it? It's part of the `damastes` package.

Here is the ghost:

```
$ locate procrustes
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/procrustes
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/procrustes/__init__.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/procrustes/__pycache__
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/procrustes/procrustes.py
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/procrustes/run.py
```

Is there a legitimate way to pinpoint and clean it up? Or do I have to remove the `procrustes` directory manually?

Comment: `pip uninstall procrustes` does not do the trick?

Comment: Of course not. There has never been `$ pip install procrustes` in the first place.

Comment: It does not matter there was not an explicit `pip install procrustes`, packages can install their dependencies indirectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `procrustes.egg-info` folder is not available in the site-packages folder. That's why pip can't detect it. Remove it manually. Or install it via `pip install` and then `pip uninstall` works.

Comment: Thanks! But all this is a bit uncomfortable. What am I supposed to do to escape such cases in the future?

Comment: There is no guaranteed solution. Try to install project requirements from PyPI. Some build files might cause such problems.

Comment: I saw your other questions about this project, I think you'd better integrate all the needed functions of all files into one python file if you have enough knowledge and skills.

Comment: At least, in one package, yes :)